# Failed to create provisioning profile error

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework

While I am trying to create .ipa file it shows the following error message like this.

> Failed to create provision profile
>
> There are no devices registered in your account on the developer
>   website. Plugin and select a device to have Xcode register it.
>
> No profiles for "io.bundle identifier" were found
>
> Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles
>   matching 'io.bundle identifier'.

Comment: You need to registered a device's UUID in apple developer account and update provisioning profile. You can do that by plugging in device with Xcode or directly add to register device token in developer account.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that you create the "Provisioning profile" correctly in the Apple developer web.
Second, close the Xcode, then reopen and relogin your apple account which in the Xcode account setting.

It just a normal problem in Xcode. Apple never fix it.

Comment: where should i put the file i download when creating Provisioning Profile?Note: I don't have iphone

Comment: @OliverD, just double click on the Provisioning Profile that you've downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to have a real ios device attached to your mac, this will allow you to create provisioning profile by just switching to the real device on Xcode.